# jQuery UI autocomplete: how to prefetch from ajax data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a auto-complete form that fetches result from server, but on slow connection it becomes erratic as data loading takes time. Is there anyway we can prefetch data from ajax source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer your question, prefetch is possible using synchronous AJAX. Using jQuery, it will be (check syntax since I am on phone).

```
$.ajax({
     url: "",
     async: false,
     success: function(resp)
     {}
});
```

This will make sure that your data is loaded before you publish it. But as Sinethera said, this defeats entire purpose of AJAX. If you can pre-fetch the content, that means you know the expected content. Then why not put it as a static list?

Comment: nonononononononono. There is a difference between prefetching data, and turning off "async". This will make your ajax request a blocking event, as in "don't do anything until you hear back from this url". As in "omg everything is frozen and I don't know why". There is almost no reason, ever, to set `async: false`. This is no longer an Asynchronous JavaScript and XML request, it's now SJAX ;)

Comment: But that is the only way of making sure the data will be fetched before the component is loaded. I know its a real bad thing. So I have said `this defeats entire purpose of AJAX`

Comment: No, there's a difference between "getting the data first", and "shutting down the browser while I go to get data". Putting the `.autocomplete()` in the callback to a regular ajax request is fine (pointless, but fine), turning off async is never okay.

Answer (score 1):

Prefetch? Isn't that called "not being ajax"? Just load the data with the page and use it as a static data source.

Optionally get the data when they "focus" the field. That would be the only real compromise between getting the data on page-load and doing a legitimate dynamic source.